# Creating HTML tags using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am looking for a javascript function that will be able to turn:

```
- point one
- point two
- point three
```

into HTML:

```
<li>point one</li><li>point two</li><li>point three</li>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and consider editing your question a bit.  Specifically, please include more details about your problem, especially example code that you've written to try to solve it and an explanation about why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is a string (e.g. `"- point one\n- point two..."`) and you want your output as a string:

```js
function convertListItemsToLiTags(s) {
  return (""+s).replace(/^-\s*(.*?)\s*$/gm, function(s, m1) {
    return "<li>" + m1 + "</li>";
  });
}
```

Comment: This is a function of pure beauty! Thank you - it works a treat.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you think that this answer solves your problem then consider pressing the checkmark next to it to indicate that this is the "right" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to an HTML string by removing the unwanted bits an inserting appropriate tags:

```
var s = "- point one\n- point two\n- point three"

// <li>point one<li>point two<li>point three
var html = '<li>' + s.replace(/- /g,'').split('\n').join('<li>');
```

Comment: Change end to `.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";`

Comment: There is no need for LI closing tags, the markup is valid without them, so why put them in?

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought HTML wanted a more regular syntax at least for LI elements. In any case, it depends on whether or not the OP wants the closing tags (as in his example).